# Passing DbContext to other methods in the same class

Tags: entity-framework-core

So I have a method that is getting rather long and want to branch it out a bit.  From the method Im wanting to branch out, I want to call another method and have work done there that involves some lookups etc as well as adding new entities. What is the best way to pass DbContext from the primary method to the others?  By ref or not?

Action: Login

```
  MyLogCtx ctx = new MyLogCtx()
  var temp = context.Users.Where(m => m.user_unique_id ==1).FirstOrDefault();
  temp.timestamp = new DateTime();
  temp.AddLog("Login", ctx);
```

Function: AddLog

```
 // should I mark MyLogCtx as ref?
     public void AddLog(string activity, MyLogCtx context)
        {

            // want to add new log but in the original context, use ref?

            var log = new UserLog();
            log.user_id = this.user_id;
            log.activity = activity;
            context.UserLog.Add(log);
            context.SaveChanges(); 
        }
```

Comment: If you are in a class you can keep data context in a private variable where all the methods in a class as access it. Thus, your helper method can be private and locate in the same class. If that is in a different class use a DI container to instantiate and inject the DB Context to the classes that need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly good:

```
public void AddLog(string activity, MyLogCtx context)
```

unless you would want to create a new context in `AddLog`, and pass it back to the caller, which is not what you want to do.

Comment: What then would be the effect of adding the ref modifier?

Comment: In your implementation, no effect, but setting context to a new value would pass that value back to the caller.

Comment: iif you use the above pattern then you dont have to worry about anything external modifying your context, all changes will happen within the scope of the copied context... if you use ref then the modification could possibly conflict with an external modification to the same context.

Comment: So I can both add entities within the main method and the helper method but call save changes in the main method and both sets of changes will be reflected in the results?

Comment: @bitshift - Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but it isn't always necessary. Esp. when calling methods in the same class. If this class is a service it would be normal practice for it to have a context member that's passed to it in its constructor, or created there, and disposed when the service is disposed. Then, of course, the context is available in each method.

Also when calling methods in other classes it's not always necessary to pass the context. If you use dependency injection you can define a scope within which all classes receive the same context instance. This is the standard for many mature applications and standard procedure in ASP.Net core.

Yet another way to make several classes work on the same context is using an [ambient context scope](https://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/), which is a link worth reading, even when you're not going to work with DbContextScope.

Even when one of the above applies there can be cases where you want to pass a context to a method. Of course it's perfectly valid to do so but I'd adhere to two rules of the thumb:

- Don't modify the context in the method it's passed into. This is the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Meaning: don't modify properties that define its behavior, like lazy loading or validation. And *certainly* don't replace it. Modifying its cached entities is OK, often even intended. This implies that you don't pass the context by ref. Although in c# each reference type is passed by ref implicitly, using the `ref` keyword expresses an *intention* to modify the object in the receiving method. Stay far from that.
- Don't save changes in the receiving method. Part of EF best practices is to use a context as a Unit of Work, which means: use the context for a business process, call `SaveChanges` once, and dispose it. Most of the times it should be the calling method that orchestrates the UoW and, hence, should call `SaveChanges`.